# Managing branches and committs

Tags: tortoisegit

I am not sure of the right place to ask this question as it is about procedure as opposed to programming. If it can be moved to the right location I would appreciate it.

I am continuing to learn the concepts of version control and **TortoiseGit**. But I am not sure on a concept ...

```
I have project A.
    I am working on FEATURE BRANCH X.
        I am not finished with FEATURE BRANCH X just yet.
    But I would like to go back to project A and make some changes.
        Then come back to FEATURE BRANCH A and continue with that branch and eventually merge it to project A.
```

I am concerned about losing commits and / or files. It has happened before to me.

Comment: Just as a side-note: Already committed states can be recovered using the RefLog dialog which holds a history of all states of a branch and also of HEAD. These can be opened in log, a branch can be created or also cherry-picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only used basic Git, but I am pretty sure that such feature exists in TortoiseGit as well, it's called stash. It helps you to save your changes without committing them to the branch. After you stash changes, you can go to any other branch and work there. When you return to the branch with stashed changes, you pop stash and now these changes are available as unstaged.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much. Learned something new.